# como recorrer un objeto y contar los numeros que son menores a 18

Tags: javascript

tengo un objeto que es invitados, me piden verificar la edad de cada persona, si es menor de 18 no ingresa a la fiesta...

```
let invitados = {
  Luna: {
      edad: 25
  },
  Sebas: {
      edad: 7
  },
  Marce: {
      edad: 34
  },
  Nicky: {
      edad: 15
  },
```

}

```
function cuantosMenores(invitados) {
```

// La funcion llamada recibe como argumento un objeto 'invitados', en el objeto tenemos objetos que representan los invitados
// a una fiesta en donde todos tienen una propiedad "edad" .
// debe retornar la cantidad de invitados que son menores de 18.

con esta funcion he conseguido ingresar a los valores de edad.

```
function cuantosMenores(invitados) {
const edades = Object.values(invitados);
edades.forEach((element) => {
console.log(element.edad)
  })
}

cuantosMenores(invitados);
```

hasta aqui llegue, con Object.values() obtengo un array de objetos y con el forEach() itero sobre este y me imprime en consola los valores de las edades pero no he logrado crear un contador para los menores de 18, tal vez el forEach no es el metodo correcto?? ayuda por favor.

Comment: Un contador es una variable (_que en tu caso inicialmente esta en cero_) y cada vez que `element.edad` cumple la condición requerida, le sumas uno. Al finalizar el análisis retornas dicha variable.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `filter` para crear un arreglo que contenga los elementos con edad >= 18 años. Luego retornar la longitud de ese arreglo:

```js
let invitados = {
  Luna: {
      edad: 25
  },
  Sebas: {
      edad: 7
  },
  Marce: {
      edad: 34
  },
  Nicky: {
      edad: 15
  },
 }
 
 function cuantosMenores(invitados) {
    const edades = Object.values(invitados);
    return edades.filter(e => e.edad < 18).length;
}

console.log(cuantosMenores(invitados));
```

Comment: ok, comprendo el Object.values y la logica del filter pero, me podrias explicar que es exactamente lo que hace la longitud?? y gracias por tu solucion, saludos.

Comment: La longitud dice cuántos registros que cumplen con la condición de edad  < 18 fueron encontrados.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás tenga más sentido definir el array de invitados de la siguiente forma:

```
let invitados = [
    {nombre:"Luna",  edad:25},
    {nombre:"Sebas", edad:7},
    {nombre:"Marce", edad:34},
    {nombre:"Nicky", edad:15},
];
```

Y luego puede utilizar la función `filter` para obtener todos los invitados menores de 18 años:

```
function cuantosMenores(invitados) {
    return invitados.filter(invitado => invitado.edad < 18)
        .length;
}

console.log(cuantosMenores(invitados));
```

Comment: me gustaria hacer eso mi amigo pero lamentablemente es un test laboral y no puedo cambiar los argumentos que recibe la funcion, igual gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

Aunque las alternativas usando filter son seguro las más idoneas.
Aquí te dejo otro modo de hacerlo.

```
let unAdmitted = [];
function getUnAdmitted (list, newList) {
  Objec.keys(list).forEach( user => {
    list[user].edad > 18 ? null : newList.push(user);
  });
};
getUnAdmitted(invitados, unAdmitted);
```

Comment: gracias pero es un test y me piden que todo el codigo este dentro de la funcion, igual tambien es una excelente resolucion del problema, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te falto definir un contador y especificar una condición para ir acumulando.

```
function cuantosMenores(invitados) 
{
  const edades = 
        Object.values(invitados)

var cant =0;
edades.forEach((element) =>   
{  element.edad < 18 ? cant+= 1  : cant })

  return cant;
}

let invmenor = cuantosMenores(invitados);
```